# Can't boot from cloned Windows Drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, clone

I cloned my SSD to an HDD. Windows Boot Manager doesn't seem to recognize the partition and I can't boot from it even if I select the drive in the BIOS/UEFI. I deleted the other partition on the drive and tried to boot into it, it started to launch startup repair but then just took me to the recovery screen. "Set partition as active" is greyed out in Disk Management and if i try set it as active using Disk Part it says "The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks." I used AOMEI to clone the drive

Comment: Just for clarity: Is your HDD installed **internally**? (Because generally Windows Boot Manager will not boot from an external drive)

Comment: Yes it is installed internally @simon

Comment: How did you clone the disk? It seems like you cloned the partition but not the other areas such as the MBR.

Comment: hi, is there any more info you can provide in your question? Windows disk clone/boot issues can be for all sorts of reasons and you only say "I cloned my SSD to an HDD" so we don't even know what software you used--to give just one example of why I suggest providing more detail.

Comment: I used AOMEI to clone the partition @RegEdit